# Getting displayed value of select tag

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select id="kamal">
<option value"ACTIVE">a<option>
<option value"DISABLED">b<option>
<option value"DELETED">c<option>
</select>
```

I want to get the value displayed on the page..not the value shown in the option tag

I am interested in "aktiv" not "ACTIVE"

when i write `document.getElementById("kamal").value;`then the value that is select comes in the variable. But I want the displayed value.

Please help me how can I take this value.

**NOTE: By using all the options given below, it will give me the value of the selected option, I want the label of the selected option. I mean the displayed value on html page.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is:

To get the value:

```
var element = document.getElementById("kamal");
var selectedValue = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
```

To get the text:

```
var element = document.getElementById("kamal");
var selectedValue = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
```

EDIT:

working example at:

> http://jsfiddle.net/n85tW/6/

Comment: The OP wants the text, not the value.

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
var sel = document.getElementById("kamal")
alert(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value);
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/n85tW/)

Note: your `<option>` tags should be closed with `</option>`

Comment: This will give me the value of the selected option, I want the label of the selected option. I mean the displayed value on html page.

Comment: @SAM have you looked at the example i added ? this gives you the displayed text .. for example "gesperrt" not "DISABLED"

Comment: @RobG what browser are you using ? because Firefox / Chrome and IE all return the text displayed not the value.... try the example I linked in my answer

Answer (score 0):

var element = document.getElementById("kamal");
var selectedValue = element.options[element.selectedIndex].**innerHTML;**

THis was the solution of my question.